# Logitech Lua Script randomized button press in repeat loop on random sleep timers

Tags: random, lua, scripting, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

first time i try to code sth for me so....... Here i got a script that repeats (on mouse button 5 press) pushing multiple buttons with random sleep timers each after one another, checking after each button, if mouse button is still pressed. Working fine so far. Sorry for the chaotic look.

**Goal:**

- holding down button 5

  - Pressing assigned buttons (7,8,w,q,f,s) in random order,
  - random sleep timers,
  - check after each random button press if mouse button is still pressed

**Remaining Problem:**

- repeating same button order while holding down mouse button 5 (not randomized)

After hours of research i couldn't find somethin that helps me with that problem by myself, so i thought i'll try it here!

I really would appreciate some help here :)))

```
    EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
      repeat
        PressKey("8")
         Sleep(math.random(16, 21)) 
         ReleaseKey("8") 
if not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then break end
 Sleep(math.random(13, 47)) 
        PressKey("7")
         Sleep(math.random(16, 38)) 
         ReleaseKey("7") 
if not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then break end
 Sleep(math.random(13, 47)) 
        PressKey("w")
         Sleep(math.random(43, 87)) 
         ReleaseKey("w") 
if not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then break end
 Sleep(math.random(10, 49)) 
        PressKey("q")
         Sleep(math.random(16, 38)) 
         ReleaseKey("q") 
if not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then break end
 Sleep(math.random(13, 47)) 
        PressKey("w")
         Sleep(math.random(43, 87)) 
         ReleaseKey("w") 
if not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then break end
 Sleep(math.random(13, 47)) 
        PressKey("f")
         Sleep(math.random(15, 63)) 
         ReleaseKey("f") 
if not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then break end
 Sleep(math.random(13, 47)) 
        PressKey("s")
         Sleep(math.random(16, 28)) 
         ReleaseKey("s") 
if not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then break end
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
end
```

Comment: @Piglet - How setting seed value can solve the problem described?

Comment: @Schomi - Try https://pastebin.com/pASQnmy0

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff sorry missread the problem. my fault

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Just for learning and experimenting, is there a function in lua to form some kind of priority based button presses in a repeat loop? so 1 > 2 > 3 > 4...

Comment: If you want non-equal probabilities for keys: `local key = ({"8", "8", "8", "8", "7", "7", "7", "w", "w", "q", "q", "f", "s"})[math.random(13)]`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff The second thing i would like to try (if it is possible in lua) is to take your script and split it in 2 groups of 3 buttons spammed at the same time?

Comment: You can press simultaneously up to 6 keys.  This in Windows limitation.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff nah i meant the same script as posted by you but instead of 6 buttons at random, 2x 3 buttons at random at the same time with holding down 1 button. I this possible?

Comment: what means "2 groups of 3 buttons"?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I mean spamming following three buttons at random ( "7" "8" "w" ) and spamming following buttons at random ( "q" "f" "s" ) at the same time with the same button held down. So in theory it could happen that 2 buttons, (for excample 7 and f) gets pressed at the same time because they get spammed independently from each other. Or is sth. like this not possible in lua?  I reallly am a bloody amateur but having a lot of fun here xD, thanks for that already :)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Sorry, English isn't my native language, i hope that excample made it clear :)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff My take on this would be to make it that ->Mousebutton 5 presses 2 other buttons (lets say F10, F11 or G-Buttons on mouse) until Mousebutton 5 release -> F10 triggers repeated random key presses of "7" "8" "w" -> F11 triggers repeatet random key presses of "q" "f" "s"

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff The overall goal with this would be to highten the the rate every of the six button gets pressed with 2 random cycles of 3 buttons without increasing the button press speed to keep it in human limits.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/h9Epdnbd

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Works like a charm for my application! You are the best, thanks helping me here and that i could learn from you :)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Here i am again at my limit try to add sth. to the script. Would be great if you knew a way to implement it. I would like to add a press and release left mouse button after "s" or "local key2" is pressed. Dont know if thats possible tho :/

Comment: Insert (between lines #14 and #15) the line `if key2=="s" then PressMouseButton(1) Sleep(30) ReleaseMouseButton(1) end`

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply and easy solution :)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff if you have time, it would be great if you could take a look at this :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73566361/logitech-lua-toggle-between-actions-using-modifier