# Logitech Lua: Toggle between actions using modifier

Tags: random, lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I got a problem with this script and can't find a solution (if there is one). Would be great to find some help here!

Is it possible to toggle between the two repeated events (Mb5 without modifier "lshift" and Mb5 with modifier "lshift") only by pressing or releasing the "lshift" key?

**Goal:** Holding down Mb5 -> repeat action with "8" and "7" -> Keep holding down Mb5 + pressing modifier "lshift" -> repeat action with "r" and "e" -> releasing "lshift" -> back to repeating "8" and "7"

**Problem:** Script stops repeating "8" and "7" when pressing "lshift" but wont start repeating "r" and "e" and the other way around.

btw. this is not a final script but to showcase the problem.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
function OnEvent(event, arg)
        if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 and not IsModifierPressed("lshift") then
            repeat
                 local key1 = ({"8", "8"})[math.random(2)]
                 local key2 = ({"7", "7"})[math.random(2)]
        if not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then break end
                    Sleep(math.random(17, 34)) 
                    PressKey(key1)
                    Sleep(math.random(17, 34)) 
                    PressKey(key2)
        
                    Sleep(math.random(41, 85))
                    ReleaseKey(key1) 
                    Sleep(math.random(41, 85))
                    ReleaseKey(key2) 
        
              until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)   or IsModifierPressed("lshift")
    
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 and IsModifierPressed("lshift") then
        repeat
        if not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then break end
                Sleep(math.random(17, 34)) 
                PressKey("r")
                Sleep(math.random(41, 85))
                ReleaseKey("r") 
                Sleep(math.random(17, 34)) 
                PressKey("e")
                Sleep(math.random(41, 85))
                ReleaseKey("e") 
          until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)  or not IsModifierPressed("lshift")
```

Comment: anyone able to help?

Comment: push.. :).......

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking for 5 months on your question :-)

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
        repeat
            if not IsModifierPressed("lshift") then
                local key1 = ({"8", "8"})[math.random(2)]
                local key2 = ({"7", "7"})[math.random(2)]
                Sleep(math.random(17, 34))
                PressKey(key1)
                Sleep(math.random(17, 34))
                PressKey(key2)

                Sleep(math.random(41, 85))
                ReleaseKey(key1)
                Sleep(math.random(41, 85))
                ReleaseKey(key2)
            end
            if IsModifierPressed("lshift") then
                Sleep(math.random(17, 34))
                PressKey("r")
                Sleep(math.random(41, 85))
                ReleaseKey("r")
                Sleep(math.random(17, 34))
                PressKey("e")
                Sleep(math.random(41, 85))
                ReleaseKey("e")
            end
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
    end
end
```